# Python, print value and List in one line

Tags: python, printing

I know that `print itemSets` (where `itemSets` is a List) will automatically print the contents of the List in Python. I have a List of a class where each instance of the class has a List that I want to print along with another value in one line. For example, if my code was currently:

```
for i, d in enumerate(database):
    print d.itemSets
```

Is there a built in way to print `i` (or another value) along with the List (`itemSets`)? Instead of the output:

```
[{'48': 0}]
[{'46': 0}, {'40': 0}]
[{'40': 0}]
```

I would want something like:

```
0 -> [{'48': 0}]
1 -> [{'46': 0}, {'40': 0}]
2 -> [{'40': 0}]
```

The `->` is a meaningless string, it is just there so that I can read the output easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just include the index, which you've already saved to `i`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(database):
    print i, '->', d.itemSets
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `,` in print. I just tried `print i, "->", d.itemSets` and it did what I wanted. Is that how it would normally be done?

Comment: @asimes Yes, when given multiple arguments, the print function will print each separated by a space.